# Left join multiple tables onto one table python

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, left-join

Do you know how could we left join multiple table onto one table?

For instance we have 3 table:

- a has columns t and a_1
- b has colums t and b_1
- c has columns t and c_1

I would like to left join b and c to a on t in single line code:

```
a = pd.merge(a,[b,c],on='t',how='left')
```

but that does not work and I don't want to code multiple lines like first left join b to a and then c etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, in one line:

```
a.merge(b,on='t',how='left').merge(c,on='t',how='left')
```